# YouTube API v3 - Python - how to batch insert playlistItems

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been using the Youtube API to add multiple `playlistItems` to `playlists` on my profile, but doing so with loops tends to use up my daily request quota and I've hundreds to add.

- I'm sending <50 video IDs per batch
- the video IDs are all valid, and can be added succesfully one at a time

The `new_batch_http_request` method seems to be the solution but **roughly 1 in every 4 video ids within the batch ends up failing**. On Googling the problem it might be related to the `position` leading to overwrites?

Using this example, the first and third items were successful but the 2nd failed:

```py
from Google import Create_Service

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret_file.json'
API_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

playlistItemsList = ['eDTnKLqFuYU', 'TT7plfxWK6E','oMbL_7lpD1w']

batch = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=insert_video)

for videoId in playlistItemsList:
    batch.add(
        service.playlistItems().insert(part="snippet",
                                       body={"snippet": {
                                            "playlistId": "PLs7sB4wt2IftzifT5G4cdjQlXZQpEk2Go",  
                                            "position": 0,
                                            "resourceId": {"kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": videoId},
                                       }
                                       },
                                       ),
    )


request = batch.execute()
```

Using the callback function I can see that the failed attempts are returning:

```html
<HttpError 500 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&alt=json returned "Internal error encountered.". Details: "Internal error encountered.">
```

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

**Is there a way to sequentially add to playlist but utilising a batch method?**

I noticed a serialise batch request within Google API docs - could this be what I'm looking for?

https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.BatchHttpRequest-class.html#_execute

My code is based on this:

https://learndataanalysis.org/copy-videos-from-any-youtube-playlist-to-your-own-playlist-with-python-and-youtube-api/

Comment: Do note that using `new_batch_http_request` does not reduce the amount of quota units the API is accounting for your batched endpoint calls. In this context, the [meaning of batching](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/batch.md) is nothing more than: *allow your application to put several API calls into a single HTTP request.*